# Should the front end developers be levied with the responsibilities of polymorphic relations?

Tags: rest, laravel, polymorphic-associations

So I am working on an application using laravel 5 and I have a few models which are polymorphically related to many others. Example, I have comments which are related to many other models like documents and posts. So I have a polymorphic relation in between these models.

My comment table migration looks like so:

```
        Schema::create('comment', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned()->comment('Polymorphic');
            $table->string('commentable_type')->comment('Polymorphic');
            $table->integer('comment_type_id')->unsigned()->comment('Type of comment');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->comment('Id of user');
            $table->text('body')->comment('Comment as text');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('comment_type_id')->references('id')->on('comment_type')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

So now, I have the option of creating comments by doing a POST request to `/comments` and passing the `commentable_type` with the request and hence it will decide which model is the comment related to. So if I pass `post` in there, it will get related to a post.

But my employer emphasises that this would be unnecessary burden for the front end developers and they need not know about the polymorphic relationships in the back end. He suggests and alternative which also makes sense.

So when a post has a new comment, I will do a POST or a PUT on `/posts/{id}/comments` and it will create the new comment for the new post or similarly for a document.

My concern is that since we have a lot of polymorphic relations in the system, will this play well on a larger scale in the long term or would it become hard to maintain. What is the standard here or is this purely based on my own needs and perspectives?